# Download all files in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload, file

A client of ours would like us to download all the files they have stored on a SharePoint 2007 (Windows 2008 server) and upload them to their Microsoft 365 account.

The upload is simple enough, but we're seeming to have trouble downloading the files.

We were given admin access to the server and the SharePoint installation, but we just can't quite figure out how to *find* the files, let alone download them. We're lacking in the Microsoft experience :P

Could we get some guidance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread while trying to figure out how to extract multiple files from a SharePoint library all at once. When selecting more than one file, the `download a copy button became unavailable on the SharePoint Website`, as well as the extract option from the SharePoint Designer. None of the answers here worked for me (or were simple enough), but I finally came in contact with a SharePoint expert who showed me a simple button to get this done.

In the SharePoint website, go to the `library` which stores the files you wish to extract. Click the Library option at the top of the page. Among the many confusing buttons is one that says **Open with Explorer**. Click this to `open the library in Windows [File] Explorer`. From here you can select multiple files and `drag&drop` or `copy&paste` into a folder on your local machine!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This gets me 50% of the way there I think. We only have access to the admin panel "Central Administration". How would I go about locating the library?

Comment: Where are these files stored on the server?